# controlling min max of values along with intervals in geoTiff files

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to make a geoTiff value for winds where the minimum value is 5 and the maximum value is 50 at intervals of 5, so that in the geoTiff values you see contours of values 5 to 10, 10 to 15, 15 to 20, 20 to 25, 25 to 30, 30 to 35, 35 to 40, 40 to 45, and 45 to 50.

I tried to use gdal_translate scale using the below command:

```
 gdal_translate -scale 5 50 gfs_file_windonly.tiff gfs_file_windonly_adjust.tiff
```

which not only did not account for intervals of 5 but also did not make the appropriate range of values from 5 to 50 knots.  So this command did not work.  Is there any way to tweak this command or use some other command to accomplish my goal?

the original gfs_file_windonly.tiff was generated from a grib file with 0.5 degree resolution using the below snippet of code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
import numpy

ds = gdal.Open("wind.t12z.pgrb2.0p50.f000_adjust.grib2")
u = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
v = ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()

wnd=numpy.sqrt(u*u+v*v)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create("gfs_file_windonly.tiff", ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize, 4,gdal.GDT_Float32)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())

outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(wnd)
outband.SetMetadata({'name': 'wnd'})

outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(2)
outband.WriteArray(wnd)
outband.SetMetadata({'name': 'wnd'})

outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(3)
outband.WriteArray(wnd)
outband.SetMetadata({'name': 'wnd'})

outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(4)
outband.WriteArray(wnd)
outband.SetMetadata({'name': 'wnd'})

outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
outband.FlushCache()
```

Is there any way to tweak the above code to achieve the desired results?

Also how to I control colors of contours in the geotiff file to match the below color bar?

[image: desired intervals and colors for geotiff file]

Comment: I guess `xarray` could do the job... Can you share the GeoTIFF file?